# What I have to do to connect my android smartphone (Galaxy Ace S5830) to home wifi wpa2?

Tags: wi-fi, wpa2

I searched in the internet a lot, but there's no clear answer. I have Galaxy Ace s5830 with system Android. I tried connect to home wifi network (this network is secured by WPA2), but my smartphone can't connect. I putted wpa2 password correctly for sure.

When I push "Connect" button, for a while it's "Scanning...", and then says "Disconnect". If I disable security of my home wifi network, I can connect and it's working well.

I don't know where the problem is: on the android system or hardware of my smartphone, or maybe on the router.

I heard that there are problems with Android and WiFi connection by WPA2, but is there no solution or I can't find its.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some incompatibilities between Android devices and wireless routers. I've seen the same behavior on a couple of WLANs and some even go to "Acquiring IP Address..." and then disconnect. I suspect that your phone works well in other WPA2 secured WLANs?

I haven't so far seen a comprehensive list of non-functioning routers, but at least one Netgear and a locally-branded Cisco Cable modem with integrated Wifi have failed for me.

Comment: On WPA - it connects, but if I lost range, I can't connect again. This same is on WEP. Without security it works well and without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for it happened to me and a Nexus 7. My wireless router had the option of having the network run in WPA/WPA2 Personal or just WPA2. In WPA/WPA2 the Nexus 7 was stuck in a loop connecting and disconnecting from the network. Switching this to WPA2 only solved the problem for my Nexus 7. It may help in your case too.

Comment: I don't even bother trying to use WPA/WPA2 anymore. I use WPA2 alone. I haven't seen @kspacja's type of connection fail for a year now. This solution worked for me.