# Cant connect to my wifi network at home WPA/WPA2 psk

Tags: wi-fi, password

it writes saved, secured.
when I try to connect it writes connecting then back to saved secured. after a few seconds it writes authentication error. the password is right BTW

Comment: Related: [Problem connecting my Xperia L to wifi..it shows Saved ,secured with WPA2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51103/16575) – and probably [What I have to do to connect my android smartphone (Galaxy Ace S5830) to home wifi wpa2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17568/16575)